# How can I use different multiple categories for UIToolbar's?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitoolbar, objective-c-category

I have a few UIToolbars throughout my app. I want each one to have a different background. Here is an example of a Category I have:

```
#import "UIToolbar+NavBarAdditions.h"


@implementation UIToolbar (Addition)
- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIImage *barImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rowbg.png"];
    [barImage drawInRect:rect];
}
@end
```

I have a few images rowbg1, rowbg2 etc etc that I want to use for other UIToolbars that are inside of my app. How can I choose which category to use for the respective toolbar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Change a toolbar background

#### Using a subclass

A category changes all UIToolbar classes. If you need different toolbars, let each client be in charge of setting the image:

```
@interface UIBgToolbar : UIToolbar {
@private
    UIImage *_background;
}
@end
@implementation UIBgToolbar
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)aRect imagen:(UIImage*)image {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:aRect]){
        _background = [image retain];
    }
    return self;
}
- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIImage *barImage = _background;
    [barImage drawInRect:rect];
}
-(void)dealloc {
    [_background release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Usage:

```
UIImage *bg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bar_bottom.png"];
// 416 = 480 - status bar (20) - navigation bar (44)
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 416-bg.size.height, bg.size.width, bg.size.height);
UIBgToolbar *toolbar = [[UIBgToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:rect imagen:bg];
[self.view addSubview:toolbar];
[toolbar release];
```

#### Using a subview

This is an alternative way that adds a subview and doesn't need subclasses or categories:

```
UIImage *bg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bar_bottom.png"];
// 416 = 480 - status bar (20) - navigation bar (44)
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 416-bg.size.height, bg.size.width, bg.size.height);
UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:rect];

UIImageView *background = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:bg] autorelease];
background.frame = toolbar.bounds;
background.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
BOOL isIOS5 = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] intValue] >= 5;
toolbar insertSubview:background atIndex: (isIOS5 ? 1 : 0)];

[self.view addSubview:toolbar];
[toolbar release];
```

#### Making the background transparent.

Don't use this unless you really need a transparent background.

```
@interface UITransparentToolBar : UIToolbar
@end
@implementation UITransparentToolBar
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [[UIColor clearColor] set];
    CGContextFillRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), rect);
}
@end
```

Usage:

```
// create the toolbar
UIImage *bg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bar_bottom.png"];
// 416 = 480 - status bar (20) - navigation bar (44)
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 416-bg.size.height, bg.size.width, bg.size.height);
UIBgToolbar *toolbar = [[UIBgToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:rect];

// add the background
// self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
UIImageView *background = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:bg];
background.frame = toolbar.bounds;
background.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
BOOL isIOS5 = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] intValue] >= 5;
[toolbar insertSubview:background atIndex: (isIOS5 ? 1 : 0)];

[self.view addSubview:toolbar];
[toolbar release];
```

### Change a navigation bar

#### Navigation bar background

Use Noah's code in a category.

Using a subclass is also possible:

- Create a `UINavigationToolbar` subclass containing the drawRect method from Noah's answer. - Select your MainWindow.XIB, select "Navigation Bar", press ⌥⌘3 to (show Identity Inspector), and change the class to the class you just created.
- Also while in IB, press ⌥⌘4 (show Attributes Inspector) and set a number in the field Tag. If you look at Noah's code, that number decides which image to use.

#### Navigation bar toolbar background

Same thing as for a normal toolbar but using a category because the navigation toolbar is read-only:

```
// UIToolbar.h
@interface UIToolbar (Transparency)
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect;
@end
// UIToolbar.m
#import "TransparentToolbar.h"
@implementation UIToolbar (Transparency)
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [[UIColor clearColor] set];
    CGContextFillRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), rect);
}
@end
```

Usage:

```
// bar_bottom_bumped.png is a toolbar image with transparency
UIImage *bg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bar_bottom_bumped.png"];
UIImageView *background = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:bg];
background.frame = self.navigationController.toolbar.bounds;
background.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
BOOL isIOS5 = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] intValue] >= 5;
self.navigationController.toolbar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.navigationController.toolbar insertSubview:background atIndex: (isIOS5 ? 1 : 0)];
```

Comment: I like Jano's answer, but add a property to configure the background image and use that property in the drawRect: method.  This way you don't have to have a transparent uitoolbar (transparency is always expensive on cpu).

Comment: This is great. How can I make sure a UINavigationController's toolbar can use this subclass? I am accessing it via `self.navigationController.toolbar`

Comment: Are you using Interface Builder?

Comment: If you're using a XIB, then go to the MainWindow (or wherever your TabBar is located), select the UITabBarController and change the Custom Class to the one given above. If, by the contrary, you're creating the TabBarController with code, instance the above class instead of the original UITabBarController.

Comment: I removed the transparent code, since it should only be used if you really want a transparent toolbar. +1 Sam and Noah.

Answer (score 2):

If you’re creating the toolbars yourself—in IB or through code—then Jano’s solution is mostly right, though I disagree with the idea of making it transparent: you should avoid doing unnecessary blending. If you need to replace the toolbars created by a navigation controller, though, you do need to use a category rather than subclassing. You can use your existing implementation; you just need to set a different `tag` on each of the toolbars you want to have a different appearance, then check that value in your `-drawRect:`. In other words, your view controller should have something like this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    UIToolbar *toolbar = self.navigationController.toolbar;
    toolbar.tag = 3; // different value for each controller, or however you want to choose the toolbar
    [toolbar setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

and your toolbar category should have something like this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)r
{
    UIImage *barImage = nil;
    switch(self.tag)
    {
        case 1:
            barImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rowbg.png"];
            break;
        case 3:
            barImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"something else.png"];
            break;
    }

    [barImage drawInRect:self.bounds];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use **subclassing** instead of **categories**.

Comment: Can you show me an example of a subclassed UIToolbar implementation?